# Python Selenium send_keys not typing text

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to type `8` to cell by using `friday.send_keys(8)` but it doenst type number, and I dont get any error on my script too.

I can see my click is working, but send_keys is not working. I have tried multiple ways, and I have look all other SO question on this nothing really helped.

I downgrade my Firefox to 28
Selenium Version 2.53.6

[cursor looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssWRt.jpg)

```
friday = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class=' x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1111   ']")
time.sleep(5)
friday.click()
friday.send_keys(8)
```

HTML element

```
<td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1111">  
    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner" style="text-align: center; ;"></div>
</td>
```

IF you click on cell and do inspect html element adds `<input>`

```
<td id="textfield-1134-bodyEl" class="x-form-item-body" role="presentation" colspan="3" style="width: 100%;">

    <input id="textfield-1134-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-text" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="03/03/2017" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="" style="-moz-user-select: text; width: 100%;"></input>
```

Problem solver by:

```
friday_time = driver.find_element_by_name("03/03/2017")
friday_time.send_keys(8)
friday_time.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Thank you
@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: but you here type keys in a `<td>` element?

Comment: I just updated with my html element and yes it under `<td>`

Comment: But afaik you cannot type straight into a `<td>` are you sure there is no `<input>` below the `<td>`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if I click on cell and do inspect I can see `<input>` updated question again

Comment: @MahmutKilic, `input` element appears inside `<td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1111">` or `<td id="textfield-1134-bodyEl" class="x-form-item-body" role="presentation" colspan="3" style="width: 100%;">` ?

Comment: I have solved problem by using `<input>` I didnt pay attention that input appears after clicking cell